# Help Tabs with: add_help_tab() callback - How does the argument work?

Tags: contextual-help

I just tried to add a simple help tab, from within a class (example to test below). I wanted to use a helper/callback fn to prepare the content for different help tabs. According to core, the function takes some args:

> WP 3.3 /wp-admin/includes/screen.php LINE 722

```
     // If it exists, fire tab callback.
     if ( ! empty( $tab['callback'] ) )
        call_user_func_array( $tab['callback'], array( $this, $tab ) );
```

For some reason I get the complete `WP_Screen` object in the callback, instead of just the tab. See [PasteBin here](http://pastebin.com/rq2vvMv7).

Here's the example. For your convenience, as a plugin, so testing is easier (on post screens).

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Help Tab Test Case
 * Plugin URI:  http://unserkaiser.com
 * Description: Add Help Tab test case
 */
class example_help
{
    public $tabs = array(
         'EXAMPLE' => array(
             'title'   => 'TEST ME!'
            ,'content' => 'FOO'
         )
    );

   static public function init()
    {
        $class = __CLASS__ ;
        new $class;
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        add_action( "load-{$GLOBALS['pagenow']}", array( $this, 'add_tabs' ), 20 );
    }

    public function add_tabs()
    {
        foreach ( $this->tabs as $id => $data )
        {
            get_current_screen()->add_help_tab( array(
                 'id'       => $id
                ,'title'    => __( $data['title'], 'some_textdomain' )
                ,'content'  => $data['content']
                ,'callback' => array( $this, 'prepare' )
            ) );
        }
    }

    /* HELPER */
    public function prepare( $tab )
    {
error_reporting( E_ALL );
// FAILS: return blank
// _dump( $tab['tabs'] );
// No error output on screen
var_dump( $tab );

// I can dump it using my own function, 
// that adds the data to a global and then calls & prints it on shutdown
// See pastebin for content
// _dump( $tab );
        return printf( 
             '<p>%s</p>'
            ,__( 'test', 'dmb_textdomain' )
        );
    }
}
add_action( 'load-post.php', array( 'example_help', 'init' ) );
add_action( 'load-post-new.php', array( 'example_help', 'init' ) );
```

#### Edit:

If I just output `print $tab` in the callback, I get `Array` as output string *above* the actual content (`WP_Screen` is an object). I tried dumping all parts of the array without any result (white screen, no error).

Comment: I recently wrote [a tutorial for incorporating the WordPress 3.3 contextual help](http://upthemes.com/blog/2012/05/incorporating-contextual-help-and-support-into-wordpress-themes/). It might be helpful. :) Note that it is a bit of a follow-up to [Otto's original tutorial](http://ottopress.com/2011/new-in-wordpress-3-3-more-useful-help-screens/).

Comment: @ChipBennett Hope you gonna add (and link here) another update about your github stuff. I got something like this for plugin updates on plugins.php, but never considered moving this into a help tab.

Comment: Eventually; it's on the long list of things to do. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok. The answer is **NOT** simple, but after some try and error, reading core, etc. I found out what the problem is:

The callback (which should be used *instead* of the `content`) accepts two arguments: `$current_screen` and `$tab`.

Here's what `$tab` looks like, when dumped for a single tab.

```
Array
(
    [title] => TEST ME
    [id] => EXAMPLE_A
    [content] => 
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => dmb_help Object
                (
                    [tabs] => Array
                        (
                            [EXAMPLE_A] => Array
                                (
                                    [title] => TEST ME
                                    [content] => FOO
                                )

                            [EXAMPLE_B] => Array
                                (
                                    [title] => TEST ME ALSO
                                    [content] => BAR
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => prepare
        )

)
```

**IMPORTANT INFO:** You're not!! (never ever anyhow) allowed to use spaces inside an `id`-string. Then you can get the actual content from the object:

```
public function prepare( $screen, $tab )
{
    printf( 
         '<p>%s</p>'
        ,__( 
             $tab['callback'][0]->tabs[ $tab['id'] ]['content']
            ,'some_textdomain' 
         )
    );
}
```

You should drop `content` in the input array completely (until you don't want to add some repeating content when looping through multiple help tabs).

### Final working example:

Here's the working text case as plugin.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Help Tab Test Case
 * Plugin URI:  http://unserkaiser.com
 * Description: Add Help Tab test case
 */
class example_help
{
    public $tabs = array(
        // The assoc key represents the ID
        // It is NOT allowed to contain spaces
         'EXAMPLE' => array(
             'title'   => 'TEST ME!'
            ,'content' => 'FOO'
         )
    );

    static public function init()
    {
        $class = __CLASS__ ;
        new $class;
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        add_action( "load-{$GLOBALS['pagenow']}", array( $this, 'add_tabs' ), 20 );
    }

    public function add_tabs()
    {
        foreach ( $this->tabs as $id => $data )
        {
            get_current_screen()->add_help_tab( array(
                 'id'       => $id
                ,'title'    => __( $data['title'], 'some_textdomain' )
                // Use the content only if you want to add something
                // static on every help tab. Example: Another title inside the tab
                ,'content'  => '<p>Some stuff that stays above every help text</p>'
                ,'callback' => array( $this, 'prepare' )
            ) );
        }
    }

    public function prepare( $screen, $tab )
        {
            printf( 
             '<p>%s</p>'
            ,__( 
                     $tab['callback'][0]->tabs[ $tab['id'] ]['content']
                ,'dmb_textdomain' 
             )
        );
    }
}
// Always add help tabs during "load-{$GLOBALS['pagenow'}".
// There're some edge cases, as for example on reading options screen, your
// Help Tabs get loaded before the built in tabs. This seems to be a core error.
add_action( 'load-post.php', array( 'example_help', 'init' ) );
add_action( 'load-post-new.php', array( 'example_help', 'init' ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know how many or what kind of arguments reach your callback, try this two usefull php functions:

```
func_num_args()
```

and

```
func_get_args()
```

The first one shows you how many arguments are send. The second gives you an array with the arguments.

```
public function prepare(){

   echo 'Number of arguments: ' . $func_num_args();
   echo 'Arguments:';
   var_dump( func_get_args() );

}
```

Comment: The really painful thing was to find out, that I need `$tab['callback'][0]->tabs[ $tab['id'] ]['content']`, to get the actual content.